Changing PictureObject URI in Crystal Reports
I have accessed a PictureObject in my crystal report, but cannot change the URI programmatically. No method or setter method to change the URI in the PictureObject class. IS there a way to change its URI without using the Crystal Report Object Formatter?
CrystalReport1 ID = new();
PictureObject item = ID.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Picture1"] as 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.PictureObject;


The simplest option is to use a report parameter in the Graphic Location expression.
Your code can then simply set the parameter value.
Another option is to use code to set the value of a formula.
